# Translating "taller by a head"

Tags: classical-latin, english-to-latin-translation, idiom, mensura

In English one can write either of these to indicate a height difference:

> Marcus is taller than Gaius by a head.
>   Marcus is a head taller than Gaius.

I am looking for an idiomatic way to translate "by a head" in this context.
I found good adjectives for "tall" in [my previous question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/2401/79).
A simple start is to drop the measure and write simply:

> *Marcus procerior est quam Gaius.*
>   or
>   *Marcus Gaio procerior est.*

To indicate by how much someone is taller than someone else, one should use an ablative of measure (*ablativus mensurae*).
That is, *tribus metris longior* and *chiliogrammate gravius* are the correct ways to say "three meters longer" or "a kilogram heavier".
In this case, this approach leads me to these:

> *Marcus capite procerior est quam Gaius.*
>   *Marcus Gaio capite procerior est.*

I am not sure if these would be parsed correctly and especially if this would be idiomatic classical Latin.
One could read *capite* as an ablative of respect (*ablativus respectus*), leading to the interpretation that Marcus has a taller head than Gaius.
This is not what I want to say.

Perhaps one could clarify "by a head" to "by the length/height of a head".
I could use *mensura* or *altitudo* to produce:

> *Marcus mensura capitis procerior est quam Gaius.*
>   *Marcus Gaio altitudine capitis procerior est.*

This is my best guess.
**How should I translate "by a head" in this context?**
I prefer classical Latin, but I do not require it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the construction of a phrase it is good praxis to look at what classical authors (especially Cicero) did. I haven't found a comparative use of the adjective *procerus*. However, the phrase "to be taller" could be expressed with *altitudine superare* (see, for instance, Liv. 30,10,13: *altitudine aliquantum onerariae superabant* and 43,19,9: *[Perseus] altitudine muros superaret*) or *maior altitudine* (see Plin. *nat.* 8,95,1: *maior altitudine in eodem Nilo belua hippopotamius*).

In this way, translating "By a head" with *capite* couldn't be interpreted by no means as an *ablativus limitationis*. Following the precedent examples and Cic. *nat. deor.* 2,92 (*sol multis partibus maior atque amplior quam terra universa est*), your phrase should then better be translated with:

> *Marcus capite Gaium altitudine superat*

or

> *Marcus capite maior quam Gaius altitudine est*

Comment: To be helpful, an undoubted comparison of _procerus_ occurs at Suet. Aug. 73, _usus est calceamentis altiusculis, ut procerior videretur._

Answer (score 7):

You need to say taller not 'by a head', but 'by a neck'.

Ovid, Met. 3.181: . . . *collo tenus supereminet omnes*

Ovid has the same expression *collo tenus* in Met. 2.275, where the adjacent text is doubtful, but the meaning clearly the same.

Comment: *collo tenus supereminet omnes* means "she rises above all as far as the neck", which doesnt' express properly an *ablativus mensurae*.

Comment: @Alessio, I would say that 'as far as [her, the] neck she overtops all', is equivalent to 'even at neck-height she is taller than all', or 'head and shoulders above all the others'. Translated more fully, _[the nymphs, seeing a man’s face], . . . cluster round Diana to hide her with their bodies. But the goddess stood head and shoulders above all the others._

Answer (score 3):

This isn't classical Latin, but I'll mention it anyway since it might be of interest to someone. Jerome, when he translates "head and shoulders above the people" in 1 Samuel 10:23, writes *et altior fuit universo populo ab humero et sursum*.

"Head and shoulders above" is a common expression in English, and it refers to this verse.